# DataFrames - Average Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas

```
Column 1   Column 2  Column3   Column 4
   2           2         2         4
   1           2         2         3
```

I am looking to create a dataframe which contains averages of columns 1& 2, Columns 3 &4, and so on.

```
  ColumnAvg(12)      ColumnAvg(34)
      2                   3
      1.5                 1.5
```

I was using this, but it is averaging everything.

```
df.mean(axis=1)
```

Is there a way, that I can add the column headers, when averaging each row.
If not, another way would be to create two arrays, average them and then create a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `groupby` and group it with `//2' th index, which will group it by exactly 2 columns

```
  df.groupby((np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 2) + 1, axis=1).mean().add_prefix('ColumnAVg')
```

to start with index 2, as you mentioned in comment

```
 dfgrp=  df.iloc[:,2:].groupby((np.arange(len(df.iloc[:,2:].columns)) // 2) + 1, axis=1).mean().add_prefix('ColumnAVg')
 dfnew = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,2:],dfgrp])
```

Comment: I like this answer, only thing is - the first two columns are not numeric. The exactly 2 columns need to start from 3rd column. Meaning (index = 2)

Answer (score 2):

You an do `groupby` with `axis` and pass the list

```
out = df.groupby([1,1,2,2],axis=1).mean()
     1    2
0  2.0  3.0
1  1.5  2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of moving the computation into numpy is good, as it allows for multiple column pairs :

```
arr = df.to_numpy()
# split into pairs
split = np.split(arr, arr.shape[-1] // 2, axis=1)
# get mean and create dataframe
pd.DataFrame(np.mean(split, axis=0))
    0   1
0   2.0 3.0
1   1.5 2.5
```